# ERROR: CASE types numeric and character varying cannot be matched

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Hi I am new in the amazon redshift. Don't have much experience on it. I am running below query in postgre sql but getting some error. Can anyone please help me to correct the query so that i can get the correct result-

The query was in oracle format which I converted into redshift format and tried to run it but getting error.

Query:

```
select * from
(
SELECT  '01' AS record_type,
         a.fi_doc_co_cd AS fi_doc_co_cd,
         CASE When a.action_code = 'A' THEN  'A'  ELSE 'C' END AS action_code,
         a.fi_doc_no AS fi_doc_no,
         a.fi_doc_fiscal_yr AS fi_doc_fiscal_yr,
         a.bu_cd AS business_unit, 00 AS line_number,
         00 AS split_line_number, a.row_updt_tms AS row_added_date,
         a.suplr_id AS suplr_id, a.vndr_invc_no AS vndr_invc_no,
         CASE when  a.invc_flag =
                   'X' THEN  a.invc_gross_amt
                  ELSE a.invc_gross_amt * -1
                 END AS amount,
         CASE when a.invc_flag =
                   'X' THEN  a.sls_tax_amt
                  ELSE a.sls_tax_amt * -1
                 END AS sales_tax_amount,
         CASE when  a.invc_flag =
                   'X' THEN  a.frt_amt
                  ELSE a.frt_amt * -1
                 END AS freight_amount, 0 AS use_tax_amount,
         CASE when a.invc_flag =
                   'X' THEN  a.trans_invc_gross_amt
                  ELSE a.trans_invc_gross_amt * -1
                 END AS trans_amount,
         a.trans_invc_doc_currcy AS trans_currcy_cd,
         CASE when  a.invc_flag=
                   'X' THEN  a.trans_sls_tax_amt
                  ELSE a.trans_sls_tax_amt * -1
                 END AS trans_sales_tax_amt,
         CASE when a.invc_flag =
                   'X' THEN  a.trans_frt_amt
                  ELSE a.trans_frt_amt * -1
                 END AS trans_freight_amount,
         NULL AS trans_use_tax_amount, a.exchange_rate AS exchange_rate,
         a.po_suplr_id AS po_supplier, lpad(trim(a.po_no), 9, '0' ) AS po_no,
         a.po_type AS po_type, a.fi_doc_post_dt AS invoice_post_dt,
         a.invc_crt_dt AS invoice_create_date,
         a.invc_doc_type_cd AS invoice_document_type,
         a.invc_typ_cd AS invoice_type, a.invc_doc_currcy AS invoice_currency,
         a.pymt_terms AS payment_terms, a.hdr_mismatch_cd AS mismatch_code,
         NULL AS mfr_part_no, NULL AS li_descn_txt, NULL AS po_ln_no,
         NULL AS quantity, NULL AS a1099_cd, NULL AS uom_no,
         NULL AS taxg_authty_no, NULL AS tax_cd,
         NULL AS ap_department_costcenter, NULL AS ap_account,
         NULL AS ap_referencenumber, NULL AS ap_companycode,
         NULL AS ap_internalordernumber, NULL AS ap_profitcenterid,
         NULL AS lcl_fran_cd, NULL AS lcl_div_locn_cd, NULL AS lcl_deptm_cd,
         NULL AS lcl_acct_cd, NULL AS lcl_sub_cd, NULL AS lcl_refnc_cd,
         NULL AS lcl_intrn_co_cd, NULL AS lcl_plnt_cd,
         NULL AS lcl_intrn_ord_no, NULL AS lcl_wbs_no, NULL AS lcl_netw_no,
         NULL AS lcl_asset_no, NULL AS lcl_prft_ctr_no,
         NULL AS lcl_prftblty_seg_no, NULL AS lcl_prod_cd,
         NULL AS lcl_cust_no, NULL AS lcl_end_cust_no, a.sap_tcode AS tcode,
         CASE when a.sap_tcode=
                   'MR8M' THEN  a.cancel_ref_doc
                  ELSE NULL
                 END AS cancel_reference_doc,
               a.clrng_doc_no, a.clrng_doc_fiscal_yr, a.clrng_doc_co_cd,
               a.bpf_comment
    FROM sapncdb_spectrum.ap_invc a
   WHERE (   CURRENT_USER =
                (SELECT CURRENT_USER
                  WHERE CURRENT_USER IN (SELECT a.svc_acct_nm
                                   FROM sapncdb_spectrum.svc_acct_bu a
                                  WHERE CURRENT_USER = a.svc_acct_nm AND a.bu_cd = '*'))
          OR a.bu_cd IN (SELECT svc_acct_bu.bu_cd
                           FROM sapncdb_spectrum.svc_acct_bu
                          WHERE svc_acct_bu.svc_acct_nm = (SELECT CURRENT_USER
                                                            ))
         )
UNION
SELECT   '02', a.fi_doc_co_cd, CASE  a.action_code  WHEN 'A' THEN  'A'  ELSE 'C' END,
         a.fi_doc_no, a.fi_doc_fiscal_yr, a.bu_cd,
         CASE  b.src_system_invc_ln_no
                  WHEN 0 THEN  b.invc_ln_no
                  ELSE b.src_system_invc_ln_no
                 END,
         00, a.row_updt_tms, a.suplr_id, a.vndr_invc_no,
         CASE  a.invc_flag  WHEN 'X' THEN  b.invc_ln_amt  ELSE b.invc_ln_amt * -1 END,
         CASE  a.invc_flag  WHEN 'X' THEN  b.sls_tax_amt  ELSE b.sls_tax_amt * -1 END,
         CASE  a.invc_flag  WHEN 'X' THEN  b.frt_amt  ELSE b.frt_amt * -1 END,
         CASE  a.invc_flag  WHEN 'X' THEN  b.use_tax_amt  ELSE b.use_tax_amt * -1 END,
         CASE  a.invc_flag
                  WHEN 'X' THEN  b.trans_invc_ln_amt
                  ELSE b.trans_invc_ln_amt * -1
                 END,
         b.trans_currcy_cd,
         CASE  a.invc_flag
                  WHEN 'X' THEN  b.trans_sls_tax_amt
                  ELSE b.trans_sls_tax_amt * -1
                 END,
         CASE  a.invc_flag  WHEN 'X' THEN  b.trans_frt_amt  ELSE b.trans_frt_amt * -1 END,
         CASE  a.invc_flag
                  WHEN 'X' THEN  b.trans_use_tax_amt
                  ELSE b.trans_use_tax_amt * -1
                 END,
         a.exchange_rate, a.po_suplr_id, lpad(trim(a.po_no), 9, '0' ),
         a.po_type, a.fi_doc_post_dt, a.invc_crt_dt, a.invc_doc_type_cd,
         a.invc_typ_cd, a.invc_doc_currcy,
         a.pymt_terms, b.prc_mismatch || b.qty_mismatch, b.mfr_part_no,
         b.li_descn_txt, b.po_ln_no, b.li_qty, b.a1099_cd, b.uom_no,
         b.taxg_authty_no, b.tax_cd, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
         NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
         NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
                a.clrng_doc_no, a.clrng_doc_fiscal_yr, a.clrng_doc_co_cd,
                a.bpf_comment
    FROM sapncdb_spectrum.ap_invc a, sapncdb_spectrum.ap_invc_ln b
   WHERE a.fi_doc_no = b.fi_doc_no
     AND a.fi_doc_fiscal_yr = b.fi_doc_fiscal_yr
     AND a.fi_doc_co_cd = b.fi_doc_co_cd
     AND a.reqst_id = b.reqst_id
     AND (   CURRENT_USER =
                (SELECT CURRENT_USER
                  WHERE CURRENT_USER IN (SELECT a.svc_acct_nm
                                   FROM sapncdb_spectrum.svc_acct_bu a
                                  WHERE CURRENT_USER = a.svc_acct_nm AND a.bu_cd = '*'))
          OR a.bu_cd IN (SELECT svc_acct_bu.bu_cd
                           FROM sapncdb_spectrum.svc_acct_bu
                          WHERE svc_acct_bu.svc_acct_nm = (SELECT CURRENT_USER
                                                            ))
         )
UNION
SELECT   '03', a.fi_doc_co_cd,  CASE  a.action_code  WHEN 'A' THEN  'A'  ELSE 'C' END,  a.fi_doc_no,
         a.fi_doc_fiscal_yr, a.bu_cd,
         CASE  b.src_system_invc_ln_no
                  WHEN 0 THEN  b.invc_ln_no
                  ELSE b.src_system_invc_ln_no
                 END,
         CASE  c.src_system_invc_splt_ln_no
                  WHEN 0 THEN  c.invc_splt_ln_no
                  ELSE c.src_system_invc_splt_ln_no
                 END,
         a.row_updt_tms, a.suplr_id, a.vndr_invc_no,
         CASE  a.invc_flag
                  WHEN 'X' THEN  c.invc_splt_ln_amt
                  ELSE c.invc_splt_ln_amt * -1
                 END,
         CASE  a.invc_flag  WHEN 'X' THEN  c.sls_tax_amt  ELSE c.sls_tax_amt * -1 END,
         CASE  a.invc_flag  WHEN 'X' THEN  c.frt_amt  ELSE c.frt_amt * -1 END,
         CASE  a.invc_flag  WHEN 'X' THEN  c.use_tax_amt  ELSE c.use_tax_amt * -1 END,
         CASE  a.invc_flag
                  WHEN 'X' THEN  c.trans_invc_splt_ln_amt
                  ELSE c.trans_invc_splt_ln_amt * -1
                 END,
         b.trans_currcy_cd,
         CASE  a.invc_flag
                  WHEN 'X' THEN  c.trans_sls_tax_amt
                  ELSE c.trans_sls_tax_amt * -1
                 END,
         CASE  a.invc_flag  WHEN 'X' THEN  c.trans_frt_amt  ELSE c.trans_frt_amt * -1 END,
         CASE  a.invc_flag
                  WHEN 'X' THEN  c.trans_use_tax_amt
                  ELSE c.trans_use_tax_amt * -1
                 END,
         a.exchange_rate, a.po_suplr_id, lpad(trim(a.po_no), 9, '0' ),
         a.po_type, a.fi_doc_post_dt,
         a.invc_crt_dt, a.invc_doc_type_cd, a.invc_typ_cd, a.invc_doc_currcy,
         a.pymt_terms, b.prc_mismatch || b.qty_mismatch, b.mfr_part_no,
         b.li_descn_txt, b.po_ln_no, c.invc_splt_ln_qty, b.a1099_cd, b.uom_no,
         b.taxg_authty_no, b.tax_cd, c.ap_department_costcenter, c.ap_account,
         c.ap_referencenumber, c.ap_companycode, c.ap_internalordernumber,
         c.ap_profitcenterid, c.lcl_fran_cd, c.lcl_div_locn_cd,
         c.lcl_deptm_cd, c.lcl_acct_cd, c.lcl_sub_cd, c.lcl_refnc_cd,
         c.lcl_intrn_co_cd, c.lcl_plnt_cd, c.lcl_intrn_ord_no, c.lcl_wbs_no,
         c.lcl_netw_no, c.lcl_asset_no, c.lcl_prft_ctr_no,
         c.lcl_prftblty_seg_no, c.lcl_prod_cd, c.lcl_cust_no,
         c.lcl_end_cust_no, NULL, NULL, 
                a.clrng_doc_no, a.clrng_doc_fiscal_yr, a.clrng_doc_co_cd,
               a.bpf_comment
    FROM sapncdb_spectrum.ap_invc_ln b,
         sapncdb_spectrum.ap_invc a,
         sapncdb_spectrum.ap_invc_ln_acct_distn c
   WHERE a.fi_doc_no = b.fi_doc_no
     AND a.fi_doc_no = c.fi_doc_no
     AND b.fi_doc_no = c.fi_doc_no
     AND a.fi_doc_co_cd = b.fi_doc_co_cd
     AND a.fi_doc_co_cd = c.fi_doc_co_cd
     AND b.fi_doc_co_cd = c.fi_doc_co_cd
     AND a.fi_doc_fiscal_yr = b.fi_doc_fiscal_yr
     AND a.fi_doc_fiscal_yr = c.fi_doc_fiscal_yr
     AND b.fi_doc_fiscal_yr = c.fi_doc_fiscal_yr
     AND a.reqst_id = b.reqst_id
     AND a.reqst_id = c.reqst_id
     AND b.reqst_id = c.reqst_id
     AND b.invc_ln_no = c.invc_ln_no
     AND (   CURRENT_USER =
                (SELECT CURRENT_USER
                  WHERE CURRENT_USER IN (SELECT a.svc_acct_nm
                                   FROM sapncdb_spectrum.svc_acct_bu a
                                  WHERE CURRENT_USER = a.svc_acct_nm AND a.bu_cd = '*'))
          OR a.bu_cd IN (SELECT svc_acct_bu.bu_cd
                           FROM sapncdb_spectrum.svc_acct_bu
                          WHERE svc_acct_bu.svc_acct_nm = (SELECT CURRENT_USER
                                                            ))
         )
ORDER BY 2,4,5,6,9,7,8,1
) s
where rownum < 100;
```

Error:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
select * from
(
SELECT  '01' AS record_type,
         a.fi_doc_co_cd AS fi_doc_co_cd,
         CASE When a.action_code = 'A' THEN  'A'  ELSE 'C' END A...

ERROR: CASE types numeric and character varying cannot be matched [SQL State=42804]
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 0.63s
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/

Comment: The error message is saying one of your CASE statements has mismatched types.  You need to do some debug and narrow down which one (comment out portions and see which is giving the error).  Also we cannot deduce the type of your data from the query.  You need to provide some DDL information (column type) for the community to be able to assist.